# How to display specific value on other page in Meteor JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display only "title" on another page(on Dashboard.js)  by click on button which is on DescriptionForm.js form. following is html code-

```
<li class="abc">
   <h3 style="margin-left: 100px;color:orange;">
     Title:"   {{resultvar.title}}"
          <button type="submit"  name="submit" id="btn1" class="btn1 btn-warning pull-right">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;WIP&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </button>
     </h3>             
   </li>
```

Following is Helper-

```
Template.Dashboard.helpers({

    resultvar:()=> {
        var x = FlowRouter.getParam("title");
        console.log("hii");
        console.log("value of x =" + x);
        return BugDetails.findOne({'_id': x});
    },});
```

Following is event-

```
Template.DescriptionForm.events({
    'click .btn-warning': function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var title = e.target.title.value;
     console.log('title:' + title);

     console.log("You pressed the WIP button");
      FlowRouter.go('/dashboard'); 

},});
```

And on console this is my error-

title:undefined
You pressed the WIP button
hii
value of x =undefined